# Changing CSS attribute with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, attributes

Today I was shown a really simple way to change the `font-size`  of an element using jQuery.
It looked very similar to the following:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document.body) ({font-size:5em;});
</script>
```

This obviously doesn't work, but I was wondering what's missing? I remember it being just one line of code.

Note: I have tried `jQuery(document.body).css({font-size:5em;});` as well, without success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
jQuery('body').css({fontSize:'5em'});
```

Comment: Yeah, this code works! I've actually tried this in the past and it didn't work, my problem was that I kept it in the head tags instead of putting it at the bottom.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('body').css('font-size', '5em');
```

Should work.

Answer (score 2):

Quote key names and values in JavaScript object literals, and separate them with commas, don't terminate them with semi-colons.

```
{
    "font-size": "5em"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
$("body").css("font-size","70%");
</script>
```